# Editing model property inside ngRepeat, error undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm quite inexperienced with AngularJS.
I've read some answers that **might be related** but they were not clear enough for me.

[My code- Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F9OEW5iIWRU3wnHGnfaC?p=preview)

I've created a `table` using `ngRepeat` and I want to change the websites name inside this `table`
only after clicking `save button`.

But I get `error undefined`.

**My Code:**

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);


//controllers

webApp.controller ('websitesCtrl', function ($scope, Websites) {
    //$scope.x = new Website('1','3343','32434','name','privKey','pubKey','userID');
    $scope.websites  = Websites.get();



   //This function displayes site details
    $scope.expandWeb = function(website) {
        console.log('expand');
        $scope.websiteNew = angular.copy(website);
        $scope.showName = true;
    };

    $scope.saveWeb = function(websiteNew) {
        $scope.website.name = websiteNew.name;
        $scope.showName = false;
    };
});


//services

webApp.factory('Websites', function(){

    var websites = {};

    websites.get = function() {
        return [{
            id: '1',
            created: '223112',
            updated: '222212',
            name: 'google.com',
            secretKey: 'dhsd#22%$',
            publicKey: '234233@@@',
            userIdentification:'COOKIES'
          },
          {
            id: '2',
            created: '1111112',
            updated: '444412',
            name: 'walla.com',
            secretKey: 'dhsd#22%$',
            publicKey: '234233@@@',
            userIdentification:'NONE-COOKIES'
          },
                    {
            id: '3',
            created: '1111112',
            updated: '444412',
            name: 'Umms.com',
            secretKey: 'dhsd#22%$',
            publicKey: '234233@@@',
            userIdentification:'NONE-COOKIES'
          }

        ]
    };

    return websites;

});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="webApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.7" data-semver="1.0.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller='websitesCtrl'>
    <table >
    <tr ng-repeat="website in websites">
        <td>
            <a href="/websites/{{website.id}}">{{website.name}}</a>
            <button ng-click='expandWeb(website)'>edit name</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>

    <div ng-show="showName">
      <input ng-model="websiteNew.name"/>
      <button ng-click='saveWeb(websiteNew)'>save</button>
    </div>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't have $scope.webSite in saveWeb method.

Comment: So how can I access the `$scope.website`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.webSite` is undefined in `saveWeb` method. You should probably set it in `expandWeb` method.

```
$scope.expandWeb = function(website) {
    console.log('expand');
    $scope.website = website;
    $scope.websiteNew = angular.copy(website);
    $scope.showName = true;
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/beExyHMpXigVlCgJyfkF?p=preview